# Create Airflow DAG with past dagrun dates in success

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I want to create a new dag with a past start_date… for example 2023-01-01 and monthy schedule_interval.

How can I add this dag to airflow with all past runs until the actual date in success? WITHOUT ACTUALLY EXECUTE THEM.

If i deploy it at 2023-10-01 I want the dags runs from 2023-01-01, 2023-02-01, 2023-03-01, 2023-04-01, 2023-05-01… etc in success state by default.

Is this possible? Or do I have to set it manually from the ui?

I dont have access to de cli, so any solution using this tool is not valid for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [CronTriggerTimetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timetable.html#crontriggertimetable) + [catchup](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#catchup) option. Here is an example:

```
import pendulum

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.timetables.trigger import CronTriggerTimetable

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='Amil_example',
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1, tz='UTC'),
    schedule=CronTriggerTimetable('0 0 1 * *', timezone='UTC'),
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=True,
)

EmptyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='run_your_code')
```

Deploy the DAG and enable. Let's check:

```
airflow dags list-runs -d Amil_example

dag_id       | run_id                               | state   | execution_date            | start_date                       | end_date                        
=============+======================================+=========+===========================+==================================+=================================
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-10-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-10-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:06.512877+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:07.668994+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-09-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-09-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:04.777976+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:05.928701+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-08-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-08-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:02.472614+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:03.637004+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-07-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-07-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:01.054509+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:01.322897+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-06-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-06-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:59.625366+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:30:00.775684+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:57.337916+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:58.481550+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-04-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-04-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:55.911388+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:56.177813+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-03-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-03-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:53.617171+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:54.765495+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-02-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-02-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:51.022675+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:52.278873+00:00
Amil_example | scheduled__2023-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 | success | 2023-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:49.614872+00:00 | 2023-10-05T17:29:50.778296+00:00
```

[image: UI]

Comment: Do this approach execute all past dag runs? I need them not to be executed but just set as success

Comment: @Amil yes - this approach execute all past dag runs. And you can see it. Don't understand `not to be executed but just set as success` ))) You have no records in the database if they were not executed. No records = no states. You can do it manually using `sql query` if you need just update status.But this has nothing to do with historical runs

Comment: @Amil just use `return statement` or `EmptyOperator`  if you want to skip processing for some reasons. But I don't know for what is it 

Comment: Its an environment migration. I want my dags to have all historic runs in success as it is right now, but I dont need to execute it, because its a waste of resources. Im trying to find the smoothest way to do it without editing dags so much bc there are a lot.

Comment: The problem is when deploying, if catchup is false, it will do nothing, which is bad because eventually I need to rerun historic by clearing tasks. If catchup is true its also bad because executions would start and I dont want it.

Comment: @Amil I understand that you don't want  But I told you that it's impossible to set a state of something that doesn't exist. Use `catchup=True` if you need to run historical runs.  Or use `catchup=False` + `UI`( or `cli`) to run dag manually. Or connect to a host, replace operators to `EmptyOperator`, run DAG with `catchup=True`, `git checkout .` + `restart scheduler`